# Compare individual bytes with array of bytes

Tags: java, string, byte

I need to verify that a code generated in one class is same as code verified in another class. But the twist is in other class the logic used is different. Its like this.

Class A:

String = "0A2D" (suppose)
i used the substring method, take out 0A , 2D and convert them into Decimal values & store them as bytes.
the end result will look something like this

int a1 = (byte) Integer.parseInt(s,16); here s= 0A
 int a2 = (byte) Integer.parseInt(s,16); here s= 2D

so a1 would be 10 ( 1byte memory) , a2 would be 45 (1byte memory)

Class B:

In this class i'm supposed to use the method getBytes(). But when i use that I see some strange o/p saying [B@......  Firstly I need information about what is happening there actually. How is it getting encoded. Secondly the o/p here should be an array of bytes matching with o/p of Class A. i.e

byte[] b = {a1a2} ( memory 2bytes)
b = {1045}

So at the end A would be having 2 values with 1byte each. But B would have an array which would have the same two values but the memory size would be 2bytes.

I hope I'm clear in my ques & didnt confuse.

your kind help would be appreciated. thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What line of code gives the output "[B@......"? (I assume the dots mean you truncated the output.) This particular output appears as if you are trying to print the array *reference* rather than the elements of the array. You should either use a for loop to print the individual elements or use Array.toString() to get a String representation of the array.

Answer (score 0):

Your language is slightly unclear but I think the following will do what you want:

```
byte[] b = new byte[] { a1, a2 };
```

Array initializers are a very useful feature of the language.

Answer (score 0):

probably you are just printing it wrong when printing arrays use Arrays.toString(arr)

I assume when you say byte[] b = {a1a2} you mean byte[] b = {a1,a2}

Answer (score 0):

If you want to print out the contents of a byte[] you need to convert it into a String first.

Here's a useful method to convert a byte array into a readable string:

```
public static String toHexString(byte[] data)
{
    if (data == null) return "";

    char[] hexArray = {'0','1','2','3','4','5','6','7','8','9','A','B','C','D','E','F'};
    char[] hexChars = new char[data.length * 2];
    int v;

    for ( int j = 0; j < data.length; j++)
    {
        v = data[j] & 0xFF;
        hexChars[j*2] = hexArray[v/16];
        hexChars[j*2 + 1] = hexArray[v%16];
    }

    return new String(hexChars);
}
```

From there you should be able to work out the rest.